# Servo only going one direction till it reach limit

Tags: servo, attiny85

I have a ATTiny85 with a standard servo motor attached to it. I would expect the following sketch to make the servo to oscillate between position 60 and 100 but instead it just to to it's limit (180) and grinds there...

Any ideas ?

```
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <Adafruit_SoftServo.h>

Adafruit_SoftServo servo;

#define MOTOR_PIN 0

bool flip = true;

void setup() {
  if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
  // Set up the interrupt that will refresh the servo for us automagically
  OCR0A = 0xAF;            // any number is OK
  TIMSK |= _BV(OCIE0A);    // Turn on the compare interrupt (below!)

  servo.attach(MOTOR_PIN);
  servo.write(90);           // Tell servo to go to position per quirk
  delay(15);
}

void loop() {
  if(flip) {
    servo.write(60);
    delay(150);
    !flip;
  }
  else {
    servo.write(100);
    delay(150);
    !flip;
  }

  delay(500);

}

// We'll take advantage of the built in millis() timer that goes off
// to keep track of time, and refresh the servo every 20 milliseconds
volatile uint8_t counter = 0;
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  // this gets called every 2 milliseconds
  counter += 2;
  // every 20 milliseconds, refresh the servos!
  if (counter >= 20) {
    counter = 0;
    servo.refresh();
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!flip` doesn't really do anything and will probably be optimized out by the compiler. You need to save the result: `flip = !flip;`

You can simplify the code a bit:

```cpp
void loop() {
    if(flip) {
        servo.write(60);
    }
    else {
        servo.write(100);
    }
    flip = !flip;
    delay(650);
}
```

Or, get rid of the `delay` altogether:

```cpp
uint32_t last_millis = 0;    
void loop() {
    if (millis() - last_millis >= 650) {
        servo.write(flip ? 60 : 100);
        flip = !flip; 
        last_millis = millis();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was part of it (must be doing too much Ruby these days).

The other part is that I was compiling with an outdated Arduino core library... Updated and all is good now. Thanks.